# Direction of N-channel mosfet when replacing the diode in the buck convertor

Tags: mosfet, buck, polarity

In a buck-converter with a diode, in the first and second phases (on and of states) current is supposed to flow like the following circuits:
[image]

I am looking for a way to replace the diode with a MOSFET and after a few search I came by the following design:
[image]

My question is this:
considering the polarity of the N-channel MOSFET, Shouldn't the direction of the MOSFET be like the following circuit instead?

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to replace diode?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat for more power efficiency

Comment: In the second diagram you drew the NFET wrong. The body diode should "point" from the source to drain. If  you flip the body diode around you will see what Russel means. The second circuit won't work because the body diode will conduct during time when the lower NMOS is supposed to be off.

Comment: When replacing a diode with a mosfet in a DC-DC converter, the rule is that the body diode in the FET is always oriented the same way as the diode you are replacing. Otherwise it just won't work.

Comment: @mkeith thank you for your comment. I neglected the diode but basically my question was can the MOSFET conduct in the other way too?

Comment: When it is on, the mosfet conducts in both directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided enough Vgs with the correct polarity, the mosfet will conduct both ways, otherwise only through the body diode:

[image]

First cycle off, second on:

[image]

The circuit you found is the correct one. In the second you switched the symbol for the mosfet without inverting the body diode.

Comment: Thank you very much. this is what I really meant by asking the question. Please complete your answer (mention the diode problem and tell which circuit is correct)so I can accept it

Answer (score 3):

The first diagram is correct.
The FET body diode will conduct during the PFET  off cycle and the NFET being turned on bypasses this diode, reducing the voltage drop below what a diode alone can provide.

In the second diagram the NFET body diode would conduct whenever the PFET was turned on, providing a nearly hard short circuit to earth